# Convergence in expectation problem

Tags: probability-theory

How do you prove that if X converges in probability and expectation that this implies convergence in mean?  I think I have to use Chebyshev's Inequality, but am not sure how to incorporate the expectation convergence.  Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between convergence in expectation and convergence in mean?

Comment: Xn--> X in l1 is convergence in mean, and E[Xn]--> E[X] is convergence in expectation.  Sorry I don't know of a good way to type this in using Latex.

Comment: Beware that your terminology is somewhat non standard. Anyway, the result does not hold, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example which might shed some light on this question. Assume that $X_n=n$, $X_n=-n$ or $X_n=0$ with respective probabilities $a_n$, $a_n$ and $1-2a_n$. Then:

1. $X_n\to0$ in probability if and only if $a_n\to0$.
2. $\mathbb E(X_n)=0$ for every $n$, for every $(a_n)$.
3. $X_n\to0$ in $L^1$ if and only if $na_n\to0$.

In particular, $X_n\to0$ in probability and $\mathbb E(X_n)=0$ for every $n$ do not imply that $X_n\to0$ in $L^1$.